# how to get volume serial number

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am trying to get volume serial number with winapi in c++

I have the following code:

```
DWORD VolumeSerialNumber=0; 
GetVolumeInformation(L"c:\\", NULL, NULL, &VolumeSerialNumber, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

it works fine and returns `VolumeSerialNumber=571477456`
but in `cmd`, when i use `dir` I get:

```
C:\Users\User>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 2210-0DD0
```

how do i convert 571477456 to 2210-0DD0 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to print the value in hex instead of decimal, using the `%X` format specifier:

```
printf("VolumeSerialNumber: 0x%X\n", VolumeSerialNumber);
```

Which will output:

```
0x22100dd0
```

---

If you *really* require the exact same output, you can separate the `DWORD` into its lower and upper `WORDS` using the [`LOWORD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632659.aspx) and [`HIWORD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632657.aspx) macros:

```
printf("Volume Serial Number is %04X-%04X\n",
    HIWORD(VolumeSerialNumber),
    LOWORD(VolumeSerialNumber));
```

Which will output:

```
Volume Serial Number is 2210-0DD0
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to convert int to hex-string, i found this solution:

```
char Hex_output [500];
itoa (VolumeSerialNumber ,Hex_output,16);
```

Comment: You actually only need 8 characters for the hex as it's 32 bits. So ``Hex_output`` shouldn't need more than size 9. There's also the fact that itoa is a non-standard function, so a better way would either be to code one yourself or just use sprintf, analogous to Jonathon Reinhart's answer.